# How much had the rise of drones been connected with the study of birds?

Tags: biology, technology, aerodynamics

I've read in ["How do they fly" by Rudolf Dvořák](http://www.academia.cz/jak-letaji.html) that the main constraint from inventing some kind of remote-controlled flying machine that could go all directions was the lack of theoretical background that had been significantly improved with the continuing research on insect fly technology.

Is this true or were there much bigger constrains that were making it hard to construct drones apart from the lack of knowledge on aerodynamics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drones fly on the same principles as the ordinary airplanes or helicopters. So the main difficulty in developing of drones was the problem how to control them, not how to make them fly. And this problem of control has nothing to do with birds or insects.

Actually airplanes have also little to do with birds and insects because they
use different aerodynamic principles. Airplanes (gliders) can be only compared with some large birds which glide for long periods of time. Attempts to imitate
birds and insects with artificial devices were made but they were not very successful.

Comment: So it was really again only about smaller wires that could transfer the signal more efectively?

Comment: @Probably: Wires? Most drones are not controlled by wires. They are controlled by radio or have their own "artificial intellect".

Comment: @Alexandre_Eremenko No, I meant the wires inside that should provide the skill of effective information processing.

Comment: @Probably: Information processing is not provided by wires but by more sophisticated devices. Transistors, chips, etc. And by software.